# How to properly calculate the cross-correlation?

Tags: c, statistics, signal-processing, cross-correlation

I've written a program that (hopefully) calculates the cross-correlation between two signals. Although I've done a good search on how the calculation should be performed, I couldn't figure out some important details. I'm particularly concerned about the average calculation. It seems that some algorithms utilize the average of the entire data set to perform the correlation calculation for every shift (or delay). In other words, they use a constant average. I've even found some algorithms that calculate the denominator just once, using it as a constant value for the rest of the delays. However, I believe that both average and denominator should be calculated iteratively, considering only the data inside the superposition range. Therefore, I wrote two versions for this program. They seem to yield very similar results at smaller delays. I'd like to know which one is correct.

Iterative average:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

FILE *input1, *input2, *output;
int m = 0, n = 0, t;
float *VarA, *VarB, *Results, *Results2;

void open_inputs_and_output();

void count_and_check_lines();

void allocate_memory();

void read_data();

void allocate_memory2();

void write_output();

int main()
{
    float SumAverageA = 0, SumAverageB = 0, AverageA, AverageB, SubA, SubB, SumAB = 0, SumAs = 0, SumBs = 0, Correl;
    int p = 0, i, delay;

    open_inputs_and_output();

    count_and_check_lines();

    rewind(input1);
    rewind(input2);

    allocate_memory();

    read_data();

    fclose(input1);
    fclose(input2);

    printf("How many lag steps from the origin do you want to calculate?\nIf you want as many steps as the number of input points, type -1.\n");
    scanf("%i", &p);

    if(p < -1)
    {
        printf("Bad number!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(p == -1)
        t = n;
    else
        t = p;

    allocate_memory2();

    printf("\nWait...\n\n");

    for(delay = 0; delay < t; delay++)
    {
        for(i = delay; i < n; i ++)
        {
            SumAverageA += VarA[i];
            SumAverageB += VarB[(i - delay)];
        }

        AverageA = SumAverageA / (n - delay);
        AverageB = SumAverageB / (n - delay);

        for(i = delay; i < n; i++)
        {
            SubA = VarA[i] - AverageA;
            SubB = VarB[(i - delay)] - AverageB;
            SumAB += (SubA * SubB);
            SumAs += (SubA * SubA);
            SumBs += (SubB * SubB);
        }

        Correl = SumAB / (sqrt(SumAs * SumBs));

        Results[delay] = Correl;

        SumAverageA = 0;
        SumAverageB = 0;
        SumAB = 0;
        SumAs = 0;
        SumBs = 0;

        for(i = delay; i < n; i++)
        {
            SubB = VarB[i] - AverageB;
            SubA = VarA[(i - delay)] - AverageA;
            SumAB += (SubA * SubB);
            SumAs += (SubA * SubA);
            SumBs += (SubB * SubB);
        }

        Correl = SumAB / (sqrt(SumAs * SumBs));

        Results2[delay] = Correl;

        SumAverageA = 0;
        SumAverageB = 0;
        SumAB = 0;
        SumAs = 0;
        SumBs = 0;
    }

    printf("Calculations performed.\n");

    free(VarA);
    free(VarB);

    write_output();

    free(Results);
    free(Results2);

    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}

void open_inputs_and_output()
{
    input1 = fopen("C:\\...\\test.txt","r");

    if (input1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open input 1.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Input1 opening: OK.\n");

    input2 = fopen("C:\\...\\test2.txt","r");

    if (input2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open input 2.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Input2 opening: OK.\n");

    output = fopen("C:\\...\\out.txt","w");

    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open output.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Output opening: OK.\n");
}

void count_and_check_lines()
{
    float k;

    while(fscanf(input1,"%f",&k) == 1)
        n++;

    printf("n = %i\n", n);

    while(fscanf(input2,"%f",&k) == 1)
        m++;

    printf("m = %i\n", m);

    if(m != n)
    {
        printf("Error: Number of rows does not match!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Number of rows matches.\n");
}

void allocate_memory()
{
    VarA = calloc(n, sizeof(float));

    if(VarA == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for VarA.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    VarB = calloc(m, sizeof(float));

    if(VarA == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for VarB.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void read_data()
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fscanf(input1,"%f",&VarA[i]);

    printf("Data A successfully read.\n");

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        fscanf(input2,"%f",&VarB[i]);

    printf("Data B successfully read.\n");
}

void allocate_memory2()
{
    Results = calloc(t, sizeof(float));

    if(Results == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for Results.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Results2 = calloc(t, sizeof(float));

    if(Results2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for Results2.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void write_output()
{
    int i;

    for(i = t - 1; i > 0; i--)
        fprintf(output,"-%i %f\n", i , Results2[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++)
        fprintf(output,"%i %f\n", i , Results[i]);

    printf("Results written.\n");
}
```

Constant average:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

FILE *input1, *input2, *output;
int m = 0, n = 0, t;
float *VarA, *VarB, *Results, *Results2;

void open_inputs_and_output();

void count_and_check_lines();

void allocate_memory();

void read_data();

void allocate_memory2();

void write_output();

int main()
{
    float SumAverageA = 0, SumAverageB = 0, AverageA, AverageB, SubA, SubB, SumAB = 0, SumAs = 0, SumBs = 0, Correl;
    int p = 0, i, delay;

    open_inputs_and_output();

    count_and_check_lines();

    rewind(input1);
    rewind(input2);

    allocate_memory();

    read_data();

    fclose(input1);
    fclose(input2);

    printf("How many lag steps from the origin do you want to calculate?\nIf you want as many steps as the number of input points, type -1.\n");
    scanf("%i", &p);

    if(p < -1)
    {
        printf("Bad number!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(p == -1)
        t = n;
    else
        t = p;

    allocate_memory2();

    printf("\nWait...\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        SumAverageA += VarA[i];
        SumAverageB += VarB[i];
    }

    AverageA = SumAverageA / n;
    AverageB = SumAverageB / n;

    for(delay = 0; delay < t; delay++)
    {
        for(i = delay; i < n; i++)
        {
            SubA = VarA[i] - AverageA;
            SubB = VarB[(i - delay)] - AverageB;
            SumAB += (SubA * SubB);
            SumAs += (SubA * SubA);
            SumBs += (SubB * SubB);
        }

        Correl = SumAB / (sqrt(SumAs * SumBs));

        Results[delay] = Correl;

        SumAverageA = 0;
        SumAverageB = 0;
        SumAB = 0;
        SumAs = 0;
        SumBs = 0;

        for(i = delay; i < n; i++)
        {
            SubB = VarB[i] - AverageB;
            SubA = VarA[(i - delay)] - AverageA;
            SumAB += (SubA * SubB);
            SumAs += (SubA * SubA);
            SumBs += (SubB * SubB);
        }

        Correl = SumAB / (sqrt(SumAs * SumBs));

        Results2[delay] = Correl;

        SumAverageA = 0;
        SumAverageB = 0;
        SumAB = 0;
        SumAs = 0;
        SumBs = 0;
    }

    printf("Calculations performed.\n");

    free(VarA);
    free(VarB);

    write_output();

    free(Results);
    free(Results2);

    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}

void open_inputs_and_output()
{
    input1 = fopen("C:\\...\\test.txt","r");

    if (input1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open input 1.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Input1 opening: OK.\n");

    input2 = fopen("C:\\...\\test2.txt","r");

    if (input2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open input 2.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Input2 opening: OK.\n");

    output = fopen("C:\\...\\out.txt","w");

    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open output.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Output opening: OK.\n");
}

void count_and_check_lines()
{
    float k;

    while(fscanf(input1,"%f",&k) == 1)
        n++;

    printf("n = %i\n", n);

    while(fscanf(input2,"%f",&k) == 1)
        m++;

    printf("m = %i\n", m);

    if(m != n)
    {
        printf("Error: Number of rows does not match!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Number of rows matches.\n");
}

void allocate_memory()
{
    VarA = calloc(n, sizeof(float));

    if(VarA == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for VarA.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    VarB = calloc(m, sizeof(float));

    if(VarA == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for VarB.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void read_data()
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fscanf(input1,"%f",&VarA[i]);

    printf("Data A successfully read.\n");

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        fscanf(input2,"%f",&VarB[i]);

    printf("Data B successfully read.\n");
}

void allocate_memory2()
{
    Results = calloc(t, sizeof(float));

    if(Results == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for Results.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Results2 = calloc(t, sizeof(float));

    if(Results2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for Results2.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void write_output()
{
    int i;

    for(i = t - 1; i > 0; i--)
        fprintf(output,"-%i %f\n", i , Results2[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++)
        fprintf(output,"%i %f\n", i , Results[i]);

    printf("Results written.\n");
}
```

References:

http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2010_03/column2.pdf

http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/correlate/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry you've gotten no response in 5+ hours; that's relatively unusual. Since you seem to have found some algorithms that do things each way, maybe the answer is "each is correct when the algorithm is the one that should be used" and your problem is that you are not sure which algorithm you should be using in your situation. Which references did you read? What did they say about when the algorithm is applicable? Did they say anything about the alternatives and why you shouldn't use the other? (Add the extra information to your question, please, not as a comment.)

Comment: They don't say much about alternative methods. My method is just a logical deduction based on the analysis of the correlation equation and the cross-correlation concept. It may be correct, but it also may be incorrect. Data processing and statistics is not exactly my field.

Answer (score 0):

If your processes are [wide sense stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity), then the averages would not change over time. If the processes are also [ergodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity), then those averages can be obtained by computing the average of a single time series. In that case, you might as well use all the samples available to get as accurate an estimate of the mean as possible. This then naturally leads to your "Constant average" implementation.

If on the other hand your processes aren't wide sense stationary and ergodic, then obtaining a good estimate of their local means could prove to be a bigger challenge. Estimating the average over a smaller time window where the processes are approximately stationary could be a reasonable approach (which is similar to your "Iterative average" implementation). Note that there are other approaches and their suitability would depend on the specific application, and the specific signals' properties.

You might then be wondering how you would know whether or not your processes are wide sense stationary. Unfortunately, unless you know a lot about how those processes were generated, often the best you could do is work under the hypothesis that the processes are wide sense stationary, and then try to disprove that hypothesis (by observing results which are outside the expected ranges; see [statistical hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing)).

Comment: Thank you. It makes things clearer. I'm dealing with molecular dynamics trajectories of a protein that fluctuates between an open and a closed state (lifetimes ranging from ~5 to a few dozens of nanoseconds. Considering that in a large (but not large enough to cause protein unfolding) timescale the average should be constant, I believe the measured variables could be considered ergodic, but I'm not sure about WSS. Because at short timescales the average do change, but if the data are accumulated for larger timescales, then the averages tend to be constant.